# Used technology for xml-files in app/design folder

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

I try to reach a better understanding of my Magento2 installation. I use a theme which place xml-files in app\design\frontend[,,].
I try to find out, how the xml file is used? In which way or by what technology the xml-files are interpreted?

Thanks, Mario